# Create a Job for exporting a SQL Server view into Excel on a daily basis

Tags: sql-server, excel, export

I am using SQL Server; is there a way to create a scheduled Job which is going to take a view and export it into an Excel file every day?

With the addition of: creating a new folder named by the timestamp, and the file name will have the timestamp as part of its name as well, something like

```
C:/excel/221120170830/name221120170830.exl
```

I tried looking around but so far I couldn't find any way to do it.

Maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically you need to combine 3 technologies:

1. [SQL Server Agent Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-jobs)
2. [Powershell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213688.aspx)
3. [Export Data Wizard/SSIS package](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/202/simple-way-to-export-data-from-sql-server/)

The idea is to create a job with as a first step, a Powershell script that checks if a folder exists and if not, creates it. The next step executes the SSIS package you have created, following the guidelines in the above link.

The tricky part may be uniquely naming your Excel file, but you first export the file to a temporary location and then, using another Powershell step, rename it and store it in the correct folder.